# AutoFilter Array doesn't work with more elements VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm here because are (almost two days) that I'm on the code and I need help.

The goal of my script is to filter the rows that don't have number in the column "Check_Column".

The problem is that the filter dosen't work "well" (It smees that he works per half).

My code is:

```
Sub hide_numbers()
Dim WorkBk As Workbook, WorkSh As Worksheet, FilterRow As Variant
Set WorkSh = Sheets("DataBase")
WorkSh.Activate
FilterRow = Rows("1:1").Find(what:="Check_Column", lookat:=xlWhole).Column
WorkSh.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=FilterRow, Criteria1:=Array("*1*","*2*","*3*","*4*","*5*","*6*", "*7*","*8*","*9*")
End Sub
```

If I use `(*1*","*2*")` it works, but if I use `("*1*","*2*","*3*","*4*","*5*","*6*", "*7*","*8*","*9*")` it doesn't work. Why?

Here the excel screenshot (is an example).

[image]

I'd like to have this output (is an example).

[image]

Somebody, please, could tell me whre I wrong?

Thank in advance.

Francesco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following macro uses the Dictionary object to collect the unique values from Check_Column that contains a digit, and then filters for those values.

By the way, since you want to show rows where the value in Check_Column contains a digit, it would probably be more appropriate to change the name of the sub from hide_numbers to show_numbers.

```
Option Explicit

Sub hide_numbers()

    Dim criteriaDictionary As Object
    Set criteriaDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Dim criteriaArray As Variant
    criteriaArray = Array("*1*", "*2*", "*3*", "*4*", "*5*", "*6*", "*7*", "*8*", "*9*")

    Dim databaseWorksheet As Worksheet
    Set databaseWorksheet = Worksheets("DataBase")

    With databaseWorksheet

        Dim fieldIndex As Long
        fieldIndex = .Rows("1:1").Find(what:="Check_Column", lookat:=xlWhole).Column

        Dim currentCell As Range
        Dim currentItem As Variant
        For Each currentCell In .Range(.Cells(2, fieldIndex), .Cells(.Rows.Count, fieldIndex).End(xlUp)).Cells
            For Each currentItem In criteriaArray
                If currentCell.Value Like currentItem Then
                    criteriaDictionary(currentCell.Value) = ""
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next currentItem
        Next currentCell

        If criteriaDictionary.Count > 0 Then
            With .UsedRange
                .AutoFilter field:=fieldIndex, Criteria1:=criteriaDictionary.keys(), Operator:=xlFilterValues
            End With
        Else
            MsgBox "No records found!", vbExclamation
        End If

    End With

    Set criteriaDictionary = Nothing
    Set databaseWorksheet = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for you help. @Domenic :)
I spent a lot of time trying to solve this problem.
It is amazing.

Answer (score 0):

MS Excel is not supporting wildcard in Array values. Either you can create a array of all the values with numbers and use following code:

```
WorkSh.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=FilterRow, Criteria1:=myArray, Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

or alternatively, you can add a new column in your dataset containing True/False value for relevant rows with some formula and simplify your code as follows:

```
WorkSh.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=FilterRow, Criteria1:=True
```

Comment: Thank you the answer. :) @dhirendra-kumar
Do you mean this:  myArray = Array("*1*", "*2*", "*3*", "*4*", "*5*", "*6*", "*7*", "*8*", "*9*")

Comment: Yes, or a simple approach is create a comma separated string like myString = "1, 2, abc, we 40," and split the string like myArray = Split(myString, ",") and use myArray as your Criteria1.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the Dominic answer works great.

Comment: Good that your work done. However you can remove duplicates from the your comma separated string or the splitted array to get it done.